# Add background while uploading data wp7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, loading

anyone know how to add background while uploading data ?, currently performanceprogressbar just shown while uploading data. i try to use rectangle to cover screen but its doesn't look really nice. 
current codes:

```
    ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
    Rectangle loadi![enter image description here][1]ng = new Rectangle() 
        { 
             Height = 800, 
             Width = 480, 
             Fill =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), Opacity = 0.2 
        };  

     bar.IsIndeterminate = true;
     this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(loading);
     this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(bar);
```

something like this,

any suggestion ?, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Popup](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/windows-phone/creating-a-custom-popup-in-windows-phone-7/) control? You can add other controls to it and display it whenever the loading progress changes (e.g. starts loading something).

[Here is a demo](http://blog.toetapz.com/2010/11/02/how-to-use-popup-or-childwindow-in-windows-phone-to-display-buy-now-screen-2/) you might be interested in for the situation.